# Copy a range of directories with float number naming in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, copy, range, directory

I have few thousands of folders which store some files and (the folders) are named in the following fashion:

```
0.01
0.02
.
.
.
1.01
.
.
.
```

Normally, I would use `cp -r {1..1000} some/destination`, however trying to do `cp -r {0.01..0.21} some/destination` does not work.

Also, if I would want to copy only the every fifth folder?

```
0.05
0.1
0.15
.
.
.
```

Once again, files would be in an array, and would end at a specific number, for instance `1.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the `seq` command:

> `seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST`
>
> `-f, --format=FORMAT`  use `printf` style floating-point `FORMAT`
>
> **<sub>source: `man seq`</sub>**

Thus for all folders:

```
cp -r $(seq 0.01 0.01 0.21) some/destination
```

If you want to copy only every 5th folder:

```
cp -r $(seq 0.05 0.05 0.21) some/destination
```

However, this seq will create a list of folder-names with names like 2.00. If you do not want the trailing zeros, you need to reformat it a bit by adding the flag `-f '%g'`

Comment: You beat me to the punch, `-f '%q'` to get rid of the trailing 0s :)

Comment: @PesaThe you mean `%g`? I could not find any reference to `%q` except some page stating that it will bash quote the output.

Comment: Hehe, whoops. Not `q`, I meant `g`. They look so similar! :)

Comment: Absolutely wonderful! One-liner, sort all the problems. And yes, the trailing zeros were important, because there are folder such as "0.1", "1", "10.1" and similar, which failed without formatting. Therefore `cp -r $(seq -f '%g' x.xx increment y.yy) some/destination` did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @bluecore your welcome. Please be aware that this could fail if a given directory does not exist.

Comment: @bluecore, update to previous comment. `cp` will just throw a warning but will perform still all actions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are better off using an array so that you are resilient to the issue of folders not following a strict sequence, though this is not as efficient as copying multiple directories with each invocation of `cp` as in [kvantour's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51953455/6862601) answer:

```
dirs=(*.*/)                       # get list of directories into an array
n=0
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do       # traverse the array
  (( ++n % 5 == 0 )) || continue  # skip if it is not the 5th
  cp -r -- "$dir" "$dest"         # copy!
done
```

Comment: Hm...you could get rid of the directory check by using `dirs=(*.*/)`. But more importantly, this relies on globs which are not numerically sorted. So let's say OP had many directories, going from `0.01` to `10.50`. Everything will be nice until you get to `1` which will get correctly printed. But the next one in order is `10`, resulting in incorrectly printing of `10.04`, `10.09` etc.

Comment: You are right about the glob expression, @PesaThe.  Updated the answer.  OP hasn't made it clear if he wants to follow a strict sequence.  If he wants it that way, then your point is totally right.

Comment: @codeforester thanks for the answer! However, that should not be the issue, as the folders are due to this naming because of them being from a numerical simulation. If the folders would not follow the sequence, there would be something seriously wrong.